# Give an example of a non-differentiable function f for which the limit on right hand side exists. (Thus, the formula may......

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

Give an example of a non-differentiable function f for which the limit on right hand side exists. (Thus, the formula may be seen as a generalization of derivative.)

Well, I surely can give an example of a non-differentiable function f for which the limit on right hand side exists however, I didn't understand what is between the brackets.

Comment: The right-derivative generalizes the ordinary derivative in the sense that not all functions with a right-derivative at a point will have an ordinary derivative.

Comment: This is extremely unclear. (1) By non-differentiable function, do you mean not differentiable at any point, or not differentiable at some point? (2) "for which the limit" -- the limit of the derivative (assuming the latter for (1)) or the limit of the function? (3) "on the right side" -- is this at some specific point, or at every point? (4) If the former in (3), does the point of non-differentiability coincide with the point at which the limit is taken? (4) "the formula" -- what formula, or a formula for what? (5) "between the brackets" -- there are no brackets in anything you've written.